# How to split huge GML file in Java?

Tags: java, gml

I have already an operational application but which convert gml to shape.
The requirement of the gml file size to be supported was increased to 2GB.
Upon execution, OutOfMemory exception occurs.

Any guidance on the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: What software gives the OutOfMemory exception.

Comment: My apology. I forgot to include the application. It is Java application. Perhaps, something wrong with the coding that's why the unnecessary memory usage remains.

Comment: I just want to add the split functionality when the file size is more than 1GB. What is the best approach to split a GML file?

Comment: Most of my questions indicate you should repost this on SO; you're really asking how to efficiently parse an XML document which is greater than memory in Java, which isn't a GIS or spatial question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use 64=bit OS, 64-bit Java Vm, nd extended vtd-xml. If you do all those things and have enough memory, you will be ok.